# How to compare two string on template in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to compare two string in template but always it is showing the result in else.Here I am adding my code where trans_his.trans_type= Debit but it always shows credit.

```
  {% if trans_his.trans_type == "Debit" %}
     <td>debit {{data.amount}}</td>
  {% else %}
     <td>credit {{data.amount}}</td>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you sure the case is the same? You can just do `<td>{{ trans_his.trans_type }} {{ data.amount }}</td>` and avoid a comparison all together it seems.

Comment: sorry it was my silly mistake..i get it and thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

This is always failing because **trans_his.trans_type** is not an string but a unicode or an object  that stringifies in **Debit**. If you really want to compare them, first convert this varaible **trans_his.trans_type** into string in your views by :

```
trans_his.trans_type = str(trans_his.trans_type)
```

And then compare it. Other wise use :

```
<td>{{ trans_his.trans_type }} {{ data.amount }}</td>
```

as Suggested by Anonymous.